# 32-bit Map tiles for use with leaflet

Tags: raster, gdal, leaflet, gdal2tiles

I've got a lot of single-band `Geotiff` files with the `GDT_Float32` format and I need to present these over the web, hopefully using a webmap leaflet/mapbox/googlemaps widget where clients can hover over the map and explore the values.

I've been looking at `gdal2tiles.py` but it resamples everything down to 8-bit png. Converting to 8-bit isn't going to work for me since I need to retain the precision.

Is there a solution out there for creating 32-bit png tiles for a web viewer? Should I be thinking about this another way?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what sort of information does Geotiff store in the 32 bits? Is this 32-bit color?

Comment: It's a single band so that's functionally grayscale. Think a single 2D array filled with `Float32`.

Comment: OK, so you really have/need over 4 billion shades of gray? Most people can only distinguish like 50 (I've heard...)

Comment: A fair point. I think visually 255 values would be enough but I don't want to lose the actual values of the raster which correspond to experimental results. 

Maybe I need to store that information separately? Not really sure how though

Comment: Yeah, you just need to have a set of "original" files at 32-bit colour channels, and a set of "web-ready" files at 8-bit colour. Keep them separate, and have a script to quickly produce the 8-bit ones from the 32-bit ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @IvanSanchez' suggestion I'm going g to have web-ready 8-bit rasters with accompanying json metadata files.

The metadata files have max and min values from the original 32-bit rasters which we use to interpolate the 0-255 values from the 8bit rasters so we can explore the values in real time.